# Insert data from form to database

Tags: php, database, mysql, forms

Hello people on this forum!

I have a question, I need to insert some data from a form that I created to the database , I have tried this code:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    global $wpdb;


    $tablename=$wpdb->prefix.'verstuur';

    $data=array(
        'titel' => $_POST['titel'], 
        'url' => $_POST['url'],
        'content' => $_POST['content']);


     $wpdb->insert( $tablename, $data);
}
```

The HTML code is as following:

```
<form method="POST" id="verstuur">
<label> Titel: </label>
<input name="titel" type="text" /><br>
<br>
<label> URL: </label><br>
<input name="url" type="url" />

<label> Content: </label>
<textarea cols="6" name="content" rows="8"></textarea>

<a href="https://sshm.eu" name="toevoegen">Toevoegen</a>
```

Comment: Have you created the table `$wpdb->prefix . 'verstuur'` in the database? Does [`$wpdb->print_error()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/print_error/) give you any insight?

Comment: Is the HTML form on the same page where you are processing the `$_POST` data? If not, you need to add a form `action`. Also, do you have an actual submit button? `$_POST['submit']` checks for a `submit` field - so if you aren't sending one you'll never meet the `isset` condition.

Comment: Wow silly mistake, I didn't have the input type set to submit.. Thanks for the response.